# How to programmatically change the audio output device in Angular inside Electron?

Tags: angular, typescript, electron, webrtc

I'm developing a desktop app with Angular 11 and Electron 12. The app must be able to emit sounds and the user must have the ability to change the audio output device used by the app.

So, I tried to use the [`setSinkId`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/setSinkId) WebRTC experimental feature. Electron uses Chromium, which supports this feature. So, in Electron `webPreferences` I enabled `experimentalFeatures`.

Now, the problem it's that Typescript (v4.2.3) it's not recognizing the `setSinkId` feature.

I tried to do this inside an Angular component:

[image: audio initialization]

But as you can see, I get this error message:

[image: setSinkId error]

I know, probably Typescript doesn't support this feature yet.
But then, how can I change the audio output device in Angular inside Electron?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Especially when developing an app for Electron TypeScript's default types aren't very helpful here. `setSinkId()` is supported in Chromium and therefore also available in Electron.

You could help TypeScript a litte by explicitly adding the type definition for `setSinkId()`.

```
const audio = <HTMLAudioElement & { setSinkId (deviceId: string): void }> new Audio();

audio.setSinkId('the-id-of-the-device');
```

Comment: By the way, ESLint tells me to use `as` instead of this:
 `const audio = new Audio() as HTMLAudioElement & { setSinkId (deviceId: string): void };`

Comment: I'm happy to hear that. `as` is technically the same as the `<>` syntax. But it doesn't work together with JSX. As long as you don't use JSX it's just a stylistic choice. You could even configure eslint to enforce `<>` instead of `as`. https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/consistent-type-assertions.md